# Favourites keeps duplicating

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I have 2 Windows 10 computers. Both are on a separate license but I log onto both with the same Microsoft username.

I use IE and favourites to quickly find my favourite websites. I only had a few but I'm noticing that it's duplicate. For example, if I originally had the following in Favourites:

```
Google
Bing 
SuperUser
Folder
```

The next day or time (I can't work out when this issue happens) I get

```
Google
Google(2)
Bing
Bing(2)
Folder
Folder(2)
```

And this list gets huge. I have to go into Favourites via File Explorer and remove all unwanted. I don't know why this is happening though, is there anything I can do to debug this issue?

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Hi. Not yet. Sadly although the question states `I` it's actually for a friend and I won't be seeing them until Saturday - don't worry though as I know I will come back and vote if it fixes issue (and I suspect it will)

Comment: That is certainly understandable, and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a problem with your Windows 10 Sync Settings. If that's the case, I would modify my configuration on both computers to temporarily disable synchronization for Internet Explorer settings:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Select `Accounts`
3. On the bottom-left select `Sync your settings`
4. Toggle `Internet Explorer settings` to **Off**

   [image: Sync your settings]
5. Once that is done on each machine, trim down the list of favorites on one computer so that it only contains the original bookmarks.
6. Completely delete the favorites from the *other* computer.
7. Turn Internet Explorer synchronization back *on* for the first machine with your original bookmarks.
8. After you have verified that everything appears to be working normally on the first computer, turn IE sync back on for the other machine.
9. If the problem has been alleviated, the second machine should receive one copy of the IE bookmarks from the first machine.

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html))